# Apollo Link State Error - Error sending request to origin

Tags: graphql, react-apollo

I get the following errors when signing up/signing into my mobile app using react native

```
> (node:1474) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): JsonWebTokenError: jwtmalformed
> 
> ERRO[0166] Error sending request to origin. This likely means that the origin GraphQL server did not respond to theproxied request. To resolve this, verify the Origin specification in the Engine configuration matches the corresponding GraphQL server.  error="Post http://[::]:51865/graphql: net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)" url="http://[::]:51865/graphql"
```

I isolated the error to my client state below. It likely occured due to my apollo link state query/mutation. After I remove my client state, my mobile app can sign up/sign in without problem. Once I put the client state codes back in, I get the above error again

Anyone with good grasp of react and apollo graphql can help advise where I went wrong. As the error report by apollo is rather vague (at this moment), hard for me to pin down where specifically did the error occur

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: "http://localhost:5000/graphql",
...
  clientState: {
    defaults: defaultState,
    resolvers: {
      Query: {
        getMeInfo: (_, d, { cache }) => {
          return defaultState.me;
        }
      },
      Mutation: {
        updateMeInfo: (_, { _id, email, firstName, lastName }, { cache }) => {
          // KIV
          console.log("CACHE", cache);
        },
        resetCurrentGame: (_, d, { cache }) => {
          cache.writeData({ data: defaultState });
          return defaultState.currentGame;
        },
        updateGame: (_, { index, value }, { cache }) => {
          const prevState = cache.readQuery({ query: CURRENT_GAME });
          const data = {
            currentGame: {
              ...prevState.currentGame,
              [index]: value
            }
          };
          cache.writeData({
            query: CURRENT_GAME,
            data
          });
          return data.currentGame;
        }
      }
    }
  },...
```